# CSS3 transition misfires in FireFox

Tags: firefox, css-transitions

Look at the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shnp6/18/)
The problem I'm experiencing is that the top transition of the NotificationText always fires, but the height transition on the Notification does not.
The Notification transition seems to randomly fire.
Just press the button in the JSFiddle a lot of times and you'll see what I mean.

**EDIT: When I set the timeout from 1 to 100 ms it seems to be working, don't know why. Can anybody please explain? The top transition from the text always seems to work**

**EDIT2: Found the answer :-) Look at the answer below if you want to know how I did it**

I have a notification bar with the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="WebApp_NotificationContainer">
  <div class="WebApp_Notification" style="height: 30px;">
    <div class="WebApp_NotificationText " style="top: 0px;">TESTING</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is all generated by JavaScript (also new notifications are added to the container).

```
function addNotification(){
    var eViewPort = document.body;
    var eNotificationContainer = $(".WebApp_NotificationContainer");
    var eNotification, eNotificationText, eNotificationDiv, eAllNotifications;

    var sNotification = "TEST";

    //Create the container if it doesn't already exist
    if(eNotificationContainer.length ==0){
        eNotificationContainer = document.createElement('div');
        eNotificationContainer.className = "WebApp_NotificationContainer";

        eViewPort.appendChild(eNotificationContainer);
        eNotificationContainer = $(eNotificationContainer);
    }

    //Get a reference to the notifications
    eAllNotifications = $(".WebApp_Notification");

    //Create the new notification div
    eNotification = document.createElement('div');
    eNotification.className = "WebApp_Notification";

    //Create the textnode to be shown in the notification
    eNotificationText = document.createTextNode(sNotification);

    //Create the div to contain the text
    eNotificationDiv = document.createElement('div');
    eNotificationDiv.className = "WebApp_NotificationText"; 

    eNotificationDiv.appendChild(eNotificationText);
    eNotification.appendChild(eNotificationDiv);

    //Add the notification at the top of the list
    if(eAllNotifications.length > 0){
        $(eNotification).insertBefore(eAllNotifications[0]);
    }else{
        eNotificationContainer.append(eNotification);
    }

    var y = eNotification.offsetHeight;

    eNotification.style.height = "0px";

    //For some reason we want to wait a little bit after the notification is appended for the animation to work
    setTimeout(function(){
        eNotification.style.height = "30px";
        eNotificationDiv.style.top = "0px";
    },1);
}
```

The CSS I have to manage the notifications popping up at the top of the screen and the transition for them to seem to drop down.

```
.WebApp_NotificationContainer{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: -250px;
    left: 50%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;

    background: #9EA85E;
}

.WebApp_Notification{
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
    overflow: hidden;

    top: 0px;
    transition: height, top;
    -moz-transition: height, top;
    -webkit-transition: height, top;

    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:linear;

    color: #FFF;
    background: #9EA85E;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;

    z-index: 1;

}

.WebApp_NotificationText{
    transition: top linear 1s ;
    -moz-transition: top linear 1s ;
    -webkit-transition: top linear 1s ;

    top:-30px;

    float: left;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to force the browser to apply the element’s current style that works synchronously.

I removed the timeout around the

```
eNotification.style.height = "30px";
eNotificationDiv.style.top = "0px";
```

And added:

```
window.getComputedStyle(eNotification).height;
window.getComputedStyle(eNotificationDiv).top;
```

I got the idea from the [article](http://timtaubert.de/blog/2012/09/css-transitions-for-dynamically-created-dom-elements/) written by TIM TAUBERT

Have a look at the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shnp6/19/)